# GOLANG Llamar a función definida en un mapa, desde otra función definida desde el mismo mapa

Tags: go

Estoy intentando llamar a una función definida desde dentro del mismpo mapa. El compilador de Go lanza el siguiente error: **"initialization loop"**. Este es el código:

```
var calls = map[string]func(arg string) (interface[], error) {
    "function1": func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
         // hacer cosas
         return res, nil
     },
    "function2": func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
         res, error := calls["function1"](arg) // ESTO LANZA ERRROR
         return res, nil
     },
}
```

¿ Cómo puedo llamar otras funciones desde dentro del mapa ?

Comment: Estás en SO en Español, por favor traduce tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es claro en cuanto estas haciendo un ciclo al inicializar.

Es decir, al declarar la variable `calls` declaras `function2` que depende en `function1` que todavia no ha sido declarado.

Sencillamente declara las funciones una a la vez:

```golang
    calls := make(map[string]func(arg string) (interface{}, error))

    calls["function1"] = func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
        fmt.Printf("function1 arg: %s\n", arg)
        return nil, nil
    }

    calls["function2"] = func(arg string) (interface{}, error) {
        res, err := calls["function1"](arg)
        return res, err
    }

    calls["function2"]("hola")
```

```
$ go run main.go
function1 arg: hola
```